# Click a button to show the keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, button, keyboard

I want to realize the function: when I click a button, a interface of keyboard will come out in a dependent interface. How can I do it? Just for iOS.

Comment: Why would you present a keyboard if you don't have a textField to capture it's event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your current view UITextField with frame = CGRectZero, create a reference to that textField in code and then on pressing button call becomeFirstResponder on textField.

Comment: textMontantTotal.becomeFirstResponders=YES;
when I do this, it come an error:property 'becomeFirstResponders' not found on object of type 'UITextField', do you know how to solve this?

Comment: BecomeFirstResponder is not a property, it is method on textfield. So call [textField becomeFirstResponder]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `UITextField` to your view and call then `[myTextfield becomeFirstResponder];` Its possible to set the hidden attrribute from `UITextField` to `YES` - so the user will never see the textfield. After Keyboard input is finished you can remove the `UITextField` with removeFromSuperview.

Maybe a little bit dirty,but thats the solution I used often. I wonder if the SDK provide another possibility.